# Avoid re-rendering of open layers map when context changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, openlayers

I am using an Open Layers map inside React. I am attaching it to the DOM using setTarget like so:

const mapObject = useMap(maplayers);

```
useEffect(() => {
    mapObject.setTarget(mapRef.current);
    return () => mapObject && mapObject.setTarget(undefined);
},[mapObject]);
```

Inside the useMap.js hook I am writing changes to the center and zoom of the map back to the context:

```
const {
    zoom,
    setZoom,
    center,
    setCenter,
} = useContext(MapContext);

let mapObject = null;

var projection = new olProj.Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:25832',
    units: 'm',
});

let options = {
    target: 'map',
    controls: olControl.defaults({
        rotate: false,
        zoom: false,
        attributionOptions: {
            collapsible: false,
        },
    }),
    layers: maplayers,
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: projection,
        center: center,
        zoom: zoom
    }),
};
mapObject = new ol.Map(options);

mapObject.on('moveend', (e) => {
    console.log('moveend');
    setCenter(() => e.target.getView().getCenter());
    setZoom(() => e.target.getView().getZoom());
});
```

The problem now is that the whole map gets rerendered every time the center and zoom change. How can I avoid this? The only idea I have is to use useEffect with a dependency array that misses center and zoom but I know this is bad practise and should not be done.

Answer (score 2):

You just discovered why one should not use `useEffect` to create Openlayers components in React. I answer this question once per week here - I will probably end up writing a very long and detailed answer and then start marking those questions as duplicates. Or maybe write a tutorial for Openlayers + React.

What you are trying to achieve is not easy and no one got it right the first time. I am the author of rlayers - https://github.com/mmomtchev/rlayers - a set of components for using Openlayers in React. **The only reliable way to do everything that React expects is to use class-based components and to completely rewrite the React component life-cycle**. You are free to use my components - either directly, either as an inspiration for writing your own.

In your particular case, the problem is that you create a new `mapObject` every time the hook is called. React detects this change and decides that the component must be rerendered. Built-in React hooks work around this by memoizing the value. Your hook should declare the dependencies of the `mapObject` and then use `React.useMemo` to always return the same object:

```js
const mapObject = React.useMemo(() => {
 // code to generate the mapObject
 return mapObject;
}, [ projection, url, /* and all other items that require rerender */ ]
);
```

This way your hook will always return the same `mapObject` and you will continue to use a `useEffect` with only the `mapObject` as a dependency - according to the React guidelines.

Comment: thx for the nice write-up! I was new to React a year ago and managed to find exactly the way you proposed. Let's leave this here if other people search for the same issue.